# How to implement Likert Scale with EntityForm?

Tags: 7, webforms, entities

I was using Webform, but I need to provide an autocomplete field to reference a node of a particular type. I see many recommendations to dump Webform and use EntityForm, but the first question type I need to reproduce is a [Likert scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likert_scale). I don't see any discussion of how to create this fundamental question type with EntityForm. Do I really need to build each Likert scale question by typing option names/ids into a select field? Would there then be a way to report on the sum of a set of items in my form?

A Likert Item is a question like "What do you think of this module? Answer 1 (strongly disagree) to 5 (strongly agree)." A Likert Scale is the sum of responses to a series of Likert Items.

Webform has a very nice implementation.

Comment: Unless there's a contrib module wrapping that functionality (can't find one after a few goole searches) I think yes, you'll be left with writing out the options for each question into a multiple list field, then using a custom-themed radio widget for the form inputs themselves

Answer (score 0):

> [...] you can make form elements that don't have directly corresponding elements in the FAPI. The "grid" component is a good example of this, and in this case, I think it's exactly what you're wanting. You can effectively create a likert scale by creating "options" along the top with these keys:

```
-2|Strongly disagree
-1|Disagree
0|Neutral
1|Agree
2|Strongly agree
```

Source: https://www.drupal.org/node/291658